# android tv-box not playing embedded videos in any browser, after uninstalling default NETFLIX app that came with the box?

Tags: video

After a lot of research I could not find an answer anywhere so please enlighten me.

I have a tanix tx3 android tv-box that comes with a pre-installed old version of Netflix app which doesn't function properly, so I uninstalled it and installed a newer version apk.

After this action, the embedded videos in any site which I browse do not work. This is valid for any android browser including chrome, firefox, opera, dolphin, duckgogo etc (all with the lastest versions)

I have tried deleting browser cache, enabling desktop site etc Nothing works. In the case of desktop site mode I get an error message "This video file cannot be played. (Error Code: 224002)"

As I have read through many sites this relates to not being able to play certain video files within HTML5. I then kept on reading about JWplayer and so on.

Obviously, when uninstalling the default box Netflix app, something else was removed from my android tv-box regarding video playback. Do you have an idea what is it and how I can fix it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Was the old Netflix app a system app? How did uninstall it (what files did you delete)? Have you checked `adb logcat` if you encounter such a non-working video?

Comment: thank you for your reply. The box came with netflix pre-installed, so I don't know if you can characterize it as a "system app" or just an older version of Netflix. I uninstalled it through the android menu option, as I would uninstall any other application. I didn't uninstall specific files, only the app itself. Can I find the adb logcat through the file manager or do I need a special app/connection with a PC? Thank you

Comment: adb works via USB and a PC connection. You need to enable developer options menu, and Android Developer Bridge (adb). On PC side you need at least a minimal adb versions (included i Android SDK by Google).

Comment: Thanx.I will look into these. In the meanwhile any thoughts about the type of files missing?